# How to troubleshoot S3 Inventory Reporting?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How can I troubleshoot why the S3 inventory reporting feature does not work? It gives me an AccessDenied error with no further information other than

> Inventory export for 2023-08-03 failed because S3 doesn’t have access to the destination bucket or KMS key. Ask the owner of the destination bucket or KMS key to grant the necessary access and then try again.

My question is not about my setup in particular, but in general. How am I supposed to troubleshoot this service when it only gets run once a day and if it fails, does not provide me with any information beyond the mentioned ambiguous error message?

I understand there is no way to manually trigger the job that generates the report. Is that correct?

Does it retry when it fails? When? How many times?

Do I have to wait another day when it failed once?

Comment: Did you ever find any more info on this? I've been hunting through the CloudTrail event history, but not knowing the time of the Inventory job or the user it runs under makes it challenging to find anything.

Comment: I'm afraid not... For some reason I've got it running, but I have no idea why exactly. It's been very erratic and in no way conclusive as to why it now works. There's barely any logging to speak of, let along debugging capabilities. I won't ever touch it again. I'm happy it works and since I'm luckily not part of the project anymore I do not even care if at some point it stops working again. It was a terrible experience to work with this feature, to say the least.